# runtime error of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

This code is working well in my IDE but showing RUN TIME error in online coding competition IDE, what is the cause?

Is there problem with my code? It's passing all test cases in my IDE
is it necessary to have a main function in python? If it is please explain how to write code using main function

code section:

```
t=int(input()) #input test cases from user         
an=[]          #list that contains results of all test cases
while t>0:      
    l=int(input())       #input from user on which operation to be applied
    ans=l//10             #variable that contains final answer for each test cases
    if ans!=0:
        l=l%10
    x=l//7
    if x!=0:
        l=l%7
        ans+=x

    x=l//5
    if x!=0:
        l=l%5
        ans+=x
    x=l
    if x!=0:
        ans+=x
    t-=1
    an.append(ans)
for k in an:
    print(k)
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Ares Some online competitions don't show you the exact error.

Comment: Does the online IDE use python2 or python3?

Comment: RUN TIME error   and it uses Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Use 
if **name** == '**main**':
before the start of the main code from where you are going to take input from the user